# Updating the version of Spring data from 1.3.0 to 1.4.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-data

I am currently using Spring data version 1.3.0 but would like to update it to version 1.4.2 to  see if that resolves a "race condition" bug that i came across.

My question is if i update the spring data version do i have to also update the hibernate, spring versions as well to a specific dependent version? i.e. will spring data 1.4.2 work with  any version of hibernate or is there a version dependent between the difference dependencies?

Here are the versions i am currently using

```
<spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
<aspectj.version>1.6.12</aspectj.version>
<hibernate-core-version>4.1.12.Final</hibernate-core-version
<hibernate-ehcache-version>4.1.12.Final</hibernate-ehcache-version>
```

Also are there other libraries that depend on spring data.

My main question really is are there dependencies on the versions used for these libraries (hibernate, spring, spring data etc). If there is, how do i find out what the dependency is?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try it? Read the POM?

Comment: Well i can build it with no errors but that does not rule out run time errors. I am not a Maven expert but will try and see if i can find the dependencies from the POM.

Comment: If there are runtime errors, then that's a bug in the POM for the specific projects and should be filed there.